# Increase Filter Limit in Apache Superset

Tags: visualization, apache-superset

I am trying to create a filter for a field that contains over 5000 unique values. However, the filter's query is automatically setting a limit of 1000 rows, meaning that the majority of the values do not get displayed in the filter dropdown.

I updated the config.py file inside the 'anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages' directory by increasing the `DEFAULT_SQLLAB_LIMIT` and `QUERY_SEARCH_LIMIT` to 6000, however this did not work.

Is there any other config that I need to update?

P.S - The code snippet below shows the json representation of the filter where the issue seems to be coming from.

```
"query": "SELECT casenumber AS casenumber\nFROM pa_permits_2019\nGROUP BY casenumber\nORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC\nLIMIT 1000\nOFFSET 0"
```

Answer (score 4):

After using the grep command to find all files containing the text '1000', I found out the the filter limit can be configured through the `filter_row_limit` in viz.py